# Custom Listadapter Filterable no results

Tags: android, filter, arraylist, hashmap, custom-adapter

I am struggling with this problem for a while now. I am building a filterable list with edittext. The list populated fine initially BUT once I type something in the edittext field. The whole list is gone and returns no results. The following are my codes.

Note: My codes are mainly based on sacoskun's [post](http://www.sacoskun.com/2008/08/autocompletetextview-with-simpleadapter.html).

ThreedListViewActivity.java

```
public class ThreedListViewActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
ThreedListAdapterFilterable adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
EditText filterText = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.threed_listview);
    setTitle(R.string.view_3d);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ThreedListAdapterFilterable(this, songsList);

    new MyAsyncTask().execute();

    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    }

};

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    private final ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(ThreedListViewActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        if(dialog.isShowing() == true)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
         // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_items, menu);

    return true;
}

}
```

ThreedListAdapterFilterable.java

```
public class ThreedListAdapterFilterable extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private Activity activity;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataShown;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mAllData;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public ThreedListAdapterFilterable(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    mDataShown= (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) d;
    mAllData = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) mDataShown.clone();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return mDataShown.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.threed_listrow, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = mDataShown.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(ThreedListViewActivity.KEY_TITLE));
        artist.setText(song.get(ThreedListViewActivity.KEY_ARTIST));
        duration.setText(song.get(ThreedListViewActivity.KEY_DURATION));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(ThreedListViewActivity.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
     Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
           public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                return ((HashMap<String, String>)(resultValue)).get(ThreedListViewActivity.KEY_TITLE);
           }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence s) {

                 if(s != null)
                    {
                     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tmpAllData = mAllData;
                     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tmpDataShown = mDataShown;
                     tmpDataShown.clear();  
                     for(int i = 0; i < tmpAllData.size(); i++)
                     {
                      if(tmpAllData.get(i).get(ThreedListViewActivity.KEY_TITLE).toLowerCase().startsWith(s.toString().toLowerCase()))
                      {
                       tmpDataShown.add(tmpAllData.get(i));
                      }
                     }

                     FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                     filterResults.values = tmpDataShown;
                     filterResults.count = tmpDataShown.size();
                     return filterResults;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     return new FilterResults();
                    }
            }

            @Override
               protected void publishResults(CharSequence s,
                 FilterResults results) {
                if(results != null && results.count > 0)
                {
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
               }};
               return nameFilter;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
This is an updated adapter that will filter my list. BUT, it doesnt update my list when I backspace the text in the input text.

```
public class ProjectListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

private Activity activity;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataShown;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mAllData;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filteredItems;

public ProjectListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {

    activity = a;
    mDataShown= (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) d;
    mAllData = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) mDataShown.clone();
    filteredItems = mDataShown;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mDataShown.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi;

    if(convertView==null){
        vi=new View(activity);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recents_listrow, null);
    }else{
        vi = (View)convertView;
    }
    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.company); // artist name
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
    title.setText(filteredItems.get(position).get(RecentsFragment.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(filteredItems.get(position).get(RecentsFragment.KEY_COMPANY));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(filteredItems.get(position).get(RecentsFragment.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);

    return vi;

}

public Filter getFilter() {
     Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {


                if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filt = mDataShown;
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tmpItems = mAllData;
                    filt.clear();
                                    for(int i = 0; i < tmpItems.size(); i++) {

                                      if(tmpItems.get(i).get(RecentsFragment.KEY_TITLE).toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                      {
                                          filt.add(tmpItems.get(i));
                                      }
                                    }
                                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                                    filterResults.count = filt.size();
                                    filterResults.values = filt;
                                    return filterResults;
                               }else{
                                   return new FilterResults();
                                  }

            }

            @Override
               protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                 FilterResults results) {

                mDataShown = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)results.values;

                if (results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }

               }
            };

               return nameFilter;
 }

}
```

The list fragment i am trying to implement: RecentsFragment

```
public class RecentsFragment extends ListFragment {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.sundancepost.com/ivue/projects.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_PROJECT = "project"; // parent node
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_COMPANY = "company";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

ListView list;
ProjectListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> projectsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
EditText filterText = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

}

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recents_list, container, false);
     list = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
     filterText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.filter_box);

     return view;
 }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(null == savedInstanceState){

        ConnectivityManager cMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

            new MyAsyncTask().execute();

        } else {
             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
             builder.setMessage("Please check your internet connection");
             builder.setTitle("Failed to download resources");
             builder.setCancelable(false);
             builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           return;
                       }
                   });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }

    adapter = new ProjectListAdapter(getActivity(), projectsList);
    list.requestFocus();
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title",projectsList.get(position).get(KEY_TITLE));
            intent.putExtra("company", projectsList.get(position).get(KEY_COMPANY));

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("workaround", mCurCheckPosition);
}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    private final ProgressDialog recents_dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PROJECT);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_COMPANY, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COMPANY));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            projectsList.add(map);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        projectsList.clear();
        recents_dialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        recents_dialog.show();
        recents_dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        if(recents_dialog.isShowing() == true)
        {
            recents_dialog.dismiss();
        }
         // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}


}
```

Comment: Use the debugger. Put some breakpoints in your adapter. Does the filter actually return any results? Is publishResults ever called?

Comment: I think the results being published are not passed into the getView function. So, the list is not updated. Thanks for the reminder, @ChristopherPerry

Answer (score 0):

public class FriendsListActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Handler mHandler;
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_INSTALLED = "installed";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "picture";
    protected ListView friendsList;
    protected static JSONArray jsonArray;
    FriendsListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList> friendslist;
    EditText filterText;
    String apiResponse;
    Button play, invite;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.friends_list);
    friendslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    mHandler = new Handler();
    ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
    actionBar.setTitle("Facebook Friends");
    actionBar.setHomeAction(new IntentAction(this, TruthorDareActivity
            .createIntent(this), R.drawable.ic_home));
    friendsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendsList);
    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    friendsList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    friendsList.requestFocus();
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    invite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.invite);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    invite.setOnClickListener(this);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    apiResponse = extras.getString("API_RESPONSE");
    callPlayList();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    friendsList.requestFocus();
}

public void callPlayList() {
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONObject(apiResponse).getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (json_data.has("installed")
                    && json_data.getBoolean("installed") == true) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(KEY_ID, json_data.getString("id"));
                map.put(KEY_NAME, json_data.getString("name"));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, json_data.getString("picture"));
                map.put(KEY_INSTALLED, json_data.getString("installed"));
                friendslist.add(map);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    adapter = new FriendsListAdapter(FriendsListActivity.this, friendslist);
    friendsList.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void callInviteList() {
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONObject(apiResponse).getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (!json_data.has("installed")) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(KEY_ID, json_data.getString("id"));
                map.put(KEY_NAME, json_data.getString("name"));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, json_data.getString("picture"));
                map.put(KEY_INSTALLED, "false");
                friendslist.add(map);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    adapter = new FriendsListAdapter(FriendsListActivity.this, friendslist);
    friendsList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void clearAdapter(String params) {
    friendslist.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    if (params.equals("invite")) {
        callInviteList();
    } else {
        callPlayList();
    }

}

public class PostDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
        if (postId != null) {
            showToast("Message posted on the wall.");
        } else {
            showToast("No message posted on the wall.");
        }
    }
}

public void showToast(final String msg) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(FriendsListActivity.this, msg,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.play:
        clearAdapter("play");
        break;
    case R.id.invite:
        clearAdapter("invite");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

}

> The next part is the adapter class I use in a separate class file.

```
public class FriendsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private Activity activity;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> allData;
public HashMap<String, String> friends;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
private ItemsFilter mFilter;
static SharedPreferences TODLoginPrefs;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "static-access" })
public FriendsListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) d;
    allData = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) data.clone();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    TODLoginPrefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("LogInSession",
            activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list_row, null);

    TextView user = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.gname);
    Button play = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    Button invite = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnInvite);
    ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

    friends = new HashMap<String, String>();
    friends = data.get(position);

    user.setText(friends.get(FriendsListActivity.KEY_NAME));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(
            friends.get(FriendsListActivity.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    final String friendrId = (friends.get(FriendsListActivity.KEY_ID));
    final String name = (friends.get(FriendsListActivity.KEY_NAME));
    final String installed = (friends
            .get(FriendsListActivity.KEY_INSTALLED));
    if (installed.equals("false")) {
        play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        invite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    .setTitle("Create game with " + name + "?")
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    UserFunction userFunction = new UserFunction();
                                    JSONObject json_game = userFunction
                                            .newGame(
                                                    activity,
                                                    "Facebook",
                                                    TODLoginPrefs
                                                            .getString(
                                                                    "UserID",
                                                                    ""),
                                                    friendrId, null, null);
                                    if (json_game.has("success")) {
                                        activity.startActivity(new Intent(
                                                activity,
                                                TruthorDareActivity.class));
                                    } else {
                                        try {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    activity,
                                                    json_game
                                                            .getString("error_msg"),
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null).show();

        }
    });
    invite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    .setTitle("Invite " + name + "?")
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    UserFunction userFunction = new UserFunction();
                                    JSONObject json_game = userFunction
                                            .newInvite(
                                                    activity,
                                                    "Facebook",
                                                    TODLoginPrefs
                                                            .getString(
                                                                    "UserID",
                                                                    ""),
                                                    friendrId, null, null);
                                    if (json_game.has("success")) {
                                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                        params.putString("to", friendrId);
                                        params.putString(
                                                "message",
                                                activity.getResources()
                                                        .getString(
                                                                R.string.app_request_message));
                                        Utilities.facebook.dialog(activity,
                                                "apprequests", params,
                                                new AppRequestsListener());
                                    } else {
                                        try {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    activity,
                                                    json_game
                                                            .getString("error_msg"),
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null).show();

        }
    });
    return vi;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new ItemsFilter();
    }
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemsFilter extends Filter {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        return ((HashMap<String, String>) (resultValue))
                .get(FriendsListActivity.KEY_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence s) {

        if (s != null) {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tmpAllData = allData;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tmpDataShown = data;
            tmpDataShown.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < tmpAllData.size(); i++) {
                if (tmpAllData.get(i).get(FriendsListActivity.KEY_NAME)
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .startsWith(s.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    tmpDataShown.add(tmpAllData.get(i));
                }
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = tmpDataShown;
            filterResults.count = tmpDataShown.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence prefix, FilterResults results) {
        data = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) results.values;
        if (results.count > 0) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}

public class AppRequestsListener extends BaseDialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "App request sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity,
                TruthorDareActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "App request cancelled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I will definitely test this out. Thanks for your works @Parker

Comment: Hi, @Parker..I m wondering where do you apply the 'data' variable in the publishResults method? Did you modify the getView method as well?

Comment: @ Victor Yew. I edited the code here as I tried to put back your original code but forgot I used data instead of mDataShown. If you need me to post more I will. I have this code working from a model of a lazylist adapter class that I modified. Yours should now work with mDataShown instead of data.

Comment: hmm...I substituted data with mDataShown like you did. Initially, the list populated fine, but it crashed when I started to type something in the text input. It would be great if you can show me more code. Thanks.

Comment: I updated more of the code for you to try.  believe the s.toString() in your filter code is the reason it crashes.

Comment: yes this time without the crashing. BUT, interestingly, I followed exactly your code you posted, and when i start typing something, the list goes blank. For your information, I am using a list fragment. I am not sure it affects that much because I used an alternative adapter with the same fragment, this alternative can help me filter the list BUT it doesnt update the list when I backspace the input text. Please have a look at my post if you will. Thx.

Comment: First thing I see is that you have commented out your data clone. When you backspace after creating new data your code has nothing to go back on since your previous data is gone. FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults(); filterResults.values = DataShown; filterResults.count = mDataShown.size(); is also outside your if statement and you don't seem to have anything to filter against. Like in my example I am filtering against a friend's name. public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {return ((HashMap<String, String>)resultValue)).get(FriendsListActivity.KEY_NAME);}

Comment: I've modified my adapter based on what you explained. I retain the mAllData and move the FilterResults within the if statement. BUT, the result is the same when I try to filter and it goes blank. I've attached the fragment code that I've been using for both the adapters. I am wondering if there is any error in my fragment.

Comment: Sorry Victor I have been kinda busy. If you need I can just post up both of my activity codes for you to try.

Comment: It would be great if you can post them. I am still struggling on this. Anyway, you have been very kind thus far. I apologize for taking your time. Thx.

Comment: I updated and put the code up. You should only have to change to your xml calls and adjust some variables. Should be pretty self explanatory. Just put your xml call into the call playlist() and you can get rid of the clear adapter parts as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the getFilter() method try this

@Override
               protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                 FilterResults results) {

```
            mDataShown = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)results.values;
            ProjectListAdapter.this.setListData(mDataShown);
            ProjectListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        };
```

And to refresh the list on backspace

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
    if(s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
     adapter.setListData(projectListdata)
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else
     adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}
```

};

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But, is the setListData function an inherited one?

Comment: No, it is not an inherited one and i have created the method to set the list in my custom adapter.